# Docker destination directory stays empty

Tags: docker, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, home-assistant

Today I installed home assistant as docker on my banana pi but the config files are not showing up in the destination directory I am  giving him as argument. The command was:
`docker run -d --name="homeass" --privileged --restart=unless-stopped -e "TZ=Europe/Berlin" -v /home/pi/homeassistant/config --net=host homeassistant/home-assistant:stable`

the directories homeassistant and config where create before and the container is starting without problems in the logs but I cant find the config files like configuration.yaml which should be saved in "/home/pi/homeassistant/config".

Does anyone have an idea what I have to change in the command? Its no problem to create a new image since I havent done much in this one for now.

if I executed `docker container inspect homeass` I can see that the output direcoty is actually set also in the config file of the docker:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147",
        "Created": "2023-02-03T11:21:00.96540989Z",
        "Path": "/init",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2805,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-02-03T11:39:06.972601472Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-02-03T11:35:00.448917386Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a44a85612bd638627325945d65ce4b7986388ea3726b5a4a211fe0a14a251d3d",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147/9094e7a06d234f41a9cdc17010913e9e87bce3eefdab8c14e13f6ed44c410147-json.log",
        "Name": "/homeass",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": true,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [
                "label=disable"
            ],
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "f9496784c586883e1ca42736698675a224f3d11d3f4447ed5c9e0cad83c2e2cf",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/f9496784c586883e1ca42736698675a224f3d11d3f4447ed5c9e0cad83c2e2cf/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/pi/homeassistant/config",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "bpi-fabio",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "TZ=Europe/Berlin",
                "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "S6_BEHAVIOUR_IF_STAGE2_FAILS=2",
                "S6_CMD_WAIT_FOR_SERVICES_MAXTIME=0",
                "S6_CMD_WAIT_FOR_SERVICES=1",
                "S6_SERVICES_READYTIME=50",
                "WHEELS_LINKS=https://wheels.home-assistant.io/musllinux/",
                "S6_SERVICES_GRACETIME=220000"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "homeassistant/home-assistant:stable",
            "Volumes": {
                "/home/pi/homeassistant/config": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/config",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/init"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "io.hass.arch": "armv7",
                "io.hass.base.arch": "armv7",
                "io.hass.base.image": "homeassistant/armv7-base:3.16",
                "io.hass.base.name": "python",
                "io.hass.base.version": "2022.11.0",
                "io.hass.type": "core",
                "io.hass.version": "2023.2.0",
                "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "The Home Assistant Authors",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2023-02-01 18:44:18+00:00",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Open-source home automation platform running on Python 3",
                "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Apache License 2.0",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/home-assistant/core",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Home Assistant",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://www.home-assistant.io/",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "2023.2.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "420efbec5a07cdd4539104cd2d089d2178b038fcc611208e3b703fff0665f617",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "dd4b1bf855731d67ea2eaa579f723411662ae309860995d35bf19a7e0971f74a",
                    "EndpointID": "9efaa9624d61d6b1b7c27b244e683124669c9082c9180fe2a239fc95c837fa91",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `:` when copying the docker setup command from the installation instructions. Try:

```
docker run -d --name="homeass" --privileged --restart=unless-stopped -e "TZ=Europe/Berlin" -v /home/pi/homeassistant:/config --net=host homeassistant/home-assistant:stable
```

That should put the files in `/home/pi/homeassistant`.

If you do want the files to end up in `/home/pi/homeassistant/config`,
write `-v /home/pi/homeassistant/config:/config`.